# Where do I report stolen content?

Tags: support

While searching for an answer to a question, I found this post from a search listing:

[Controlling tomcat with supervisor](https://serverfault.com/questions/425132/controlling-tomcat-with-supervisor)

Several hits down, I also found this one, which appears to be stealing its content:

http://www.vvreview.com/q/answers-controlling-tomcat-with-supervisor-425132.html

The top answer, all the wording, even tags and "related questions" are lifted blatantly off a stack exchange site.

Where do I report this kind of abuse?

Comment: Normally [mSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) because it gets scanned more frequently, but here works too. It looks like their site is basically scraping Server Fault - I'll pass the report along to them what does the clobbering :)

Comment: Looks like it is indeed scraping ...for higher search engine rank perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently we have [an official mSO thread for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here)

I'll scan through and if these guys are new I'll add 'em

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this kind of this actually entirely legal as the whole of SE is Creative Commons?

Comment: i think they may still be violating the clause about attributing credit back to the original authors.

Comment: erm...yep, that sounds about right, good point, well made

Comment: "user contributions licensed under [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)" (but that *is* all the way at the bottom of the ever-growing footer-of-doom)

Comment: on the journey down : "Whoa, there's a site about bikes? nice!"

Comment: That site hasn't done attribution properly. They don't link back to SF in any way.